# How to expose module names from within src/main directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, project-structure

I would like to execute my modules as followed:

```
python -m module1
```

or

```
python -m module2
```

I've a project that contains `module1` and `module2` under this project structure:

```
my-project/
    src/
        main/
            module1/
                    module1.py
                    __init__.py
                    __main__.py
            module2/
                    module2.py
                    __init__.py
                    __main__.py

        __init__.py
        test/
    __init__.py
    setup.py
```

The `__main__.py`'s look like this:

```
from module1 import module1

print('module1 = ', module1.main())
```

The one for `module2` look the same, just calling `module2`, instead of one.

Now, when trying to call `python -m module1` or `python -m module2` I get the error that the module can't be found: `No module named module1`

Calling `python -m src.main.module1` or `python -m src.main.module2` everything works just fine. Furthermore, when changing the directory structure to:

```
my-project/
    module1/
        module1.py
        __init__.py
        __main__.py
    module2/
        module2.py
        __init__.py
        __main__.py
    test/
    __init__.py
    setup.py
```

, everything works as desired!

Is this just the python way of handling this and having `src/main` is just not a thing? Or am I missing something? I've tried to figure out some configuration that may needs changing, but I wasn't really having luck finding anything.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this again, it might be best to have a `src/main` directory within each module? This would look like this:

```
my-project/
    module1/
        src/
        __init__.py
            main/
            __init__.py
                module1.py
                __init__.py
            test/
        __init__.py
        __main__.py
    module2/
       src/
        __init__.py
            main/
            __init__.py
                module2.py
                __init__.py
            test/
        __init__.py
        __main__.py
    __init__.py
    setup.py
```

This structure seems to have the wanted cli behaviour, but still allows to structure the files nicely. One option, I guess, but not sure if this is the best option.